# The radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{0}^{\infty}P(n)x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series

I came across the following problem:

> Let $P(x)$ be a non-zero polynomial of degree $N.$ The radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{0}^{\infty}P(n)x^n$
>   (a)depends on $N,$
>   (b)is $1$ for all $N,$
>   (c)is $0$ for all $N,$
>   (d)is $\infty$ for all $N.$

My attempts:
I see that  $lim_{n\to\infty}P(n+1)/P(n)=1$,because if I take $N=2$,then we can take $P(n)=a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2$ and $P(n+1)=a_0+a_1(n+1)+a_2(n+1)^2$ and hence $\frac {P(n+1)}{P(n)}=1+\frac {a_1+(2n+1)a_2}{P(n)}$ which tends to $1$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. From here,Can i say that (b)is the right choice? Am i going in the right direction? Please comment.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: No, $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(n+1)/P(n)$ is not $\infty$.  Try again.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sir,I see that  $lim_{n\to\infty}P(n+1)/P(n)=1.$ Am i right?

Comment: Intuitively, as $n \to \infty$ we have $|P(n)| \to \infty$ polynomially if $N \geq 1$, and if $x>0$ then $x^n \to 0$ geometrically if $x<1$ (so the series converges for $x<1$) and $x^n \to \infty$ geometrically if $x>1$ (so the series diverges for $x>1$).  The radius of convergence must be exactly $1$ since geometric convergence or divergence dominates polynomial divergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.I have got it.+1 from me.

Comment: I should revise my previous comment slightly... the radius of convergence can be *at most* $1$.  The terms of the series going to zero is only a necessary condition for convergence; it is not sufficient.

Comment: @Antonio: It is sufficient for power series.

Comment: @JonasMeyer wow, I did not suspect that, but it is definitely true.  Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Actually, now I should backtrack a bit.  The possible exception is on the boundary of convergence, but that doesn't affect using your intuition because you were working with all $x<1$ (and it is already clear in this case what happens when $|x|=1$.)  In general, one can say that if $a_nz^n\to 0 $ for all $|z|<C$, then the radius of convergence is at least $C$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer right, it seems that either $\limsup |a_n z^n| = \infty$ or $= 0$ depending on whether $|z|$ is bigger or smaller than some value; at least you will be able to determine where the boundary is.  In fact if $a_n z^n = O(1)$ for some $z$, then the radius of convergence is at least $|z|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(n+1)/P(n)$?  You might want to try induction on the degree, using l'Hopital's Rule.  Or you could consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(n)/n^N$.

Comment: sir, i see that  $lim_{n\to\infty}P(n+1)/P(n)=\infty.$

Comment: @user52976, look again.

Comment: +1 to Robert for giving a useful hint instead of typing out a full answer (which would have been just as easy for him to do).